# sorting the topic's by descending ( new topics and replayed topics )

Tags: php, mysql

i am building a topic's system i use this mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `ftopics` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `full` text NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hits` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastrep` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

the column ( lastrep ) it updated when the member add a new replay for the topic

```
$time=time();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ftopics SET lastrep='$time' WHERE id='$tid'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

ok now when i want to output the threads and i want to order the topics's by ( id descending ) and also by ( lastrep descending ) in the same time.

explain>>>>

when i user post a new topic it shows in the first row in the output but when a nother user post a replay in another topic it should be shows the first one in the table output.

i used this query to output

```
$get_topics  = mysql_query("select id,catid,userid,name,date,lastrep from ftopics where catid='$catid' ORDER BY lastrep DESC, id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

i got the new topic in the first row but any replayed topic it still now going into the top.

i hope that i explained my Q in good way.

regards
Piny

Comment: Don't you want `lastrep` to be either a `int` or `datetime` column? `varchars` are compared lexicographically, which is almost certainly NOT what you want when dealing with date/times...

Comment: one is ( ID ) and the other one is ( modified date ).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have two columns in your table, one for time created and one for time modified. The 'modified' column would be the one you update when a new reply is added, but you could use the 'created' column to order by so your table is always ordered by the creation date.

Sorry if I've misunderstood.

EDIT
And you should definitely make those columns int/datetime as suggested above so the ordering is performed as you expect.

Comment: one for ID created and one for time modified dear

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a dateTime data type, use it for both date and lastRep columns. Then correct your insert and update queries to input proper dateTimes. This will probably correct the sorting issue, it is at least the first thing you should try.